# Why are form inputs being replaced by ellipses?

Tags: html, css

The inputs on a grid (table) show only when I click on them, otherwise they are replaced by 3 dots. This happens in FF and IE only, not in Chrome.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: table grid with ellipses replacing inputs]

As soon as I click on the input, it is restored.

[image: table grid with input showing after being clicked on]

Here is the stylesheet taken from Chrome:

```
element.style {
   padding-left: 0px;
   padding-right: 0px;
   white-space: inherit;
}
input[type=text] {
   height: 42px;
   padding: 0 6px 0 10px;
   font-size: 14px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0;
   -moz-border-radius: 0;
   border-radius: 0;
   border-top-color: none;
}
input[type=text] {
   margin-bottom: 0;
   border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
   -webkit-box-shadow: none;
   -moz-box-shadow: none;
   box-shadow: none;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0;
   -moz-border-radius: 0;
   border-radius: 0;
}
input[type=text] {
   background-color: #fff;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
   box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
   -webkit-transition: border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s;
   -moz-transition: border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s;
   -o-transition: border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s;
   transition: border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s;
}
input[type=text] {
   display: inline-block;
   height: 20px;
   padding: 4px 6px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   font-size: 12px;
   line-height: 20px;
   color: #555;
   -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
   -moz-border-radius: 4px;
   border-radius: 4px;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
input[type=search] {
   -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
   box-sizing: content-box;
   -webkit-appearance: textfield;
 }
 .input-xlarge {
    width: 270px;
 }
 .input-xlarge {
    width: 270px;
  }
  .k-widget, .k-widget * {
     -moz-background-clip: border-box;
     -webkit-background-clip: border-box;
     background-clip: border-box;
  }
 .k-animation-container, .k-widget, .k-widget *, .k-animation-container *, .k-widget 
 :before, .k-animation-container :after, .k-block .k-header, .k-list-container {
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
 }
 input {
    width: 210px;
 }
 label, input, button, select, textarea {
     font-size: 14px;
     font-weight: 400;
     line-height: 20px;
 }
 input, textarea, .uneditable-input {
    margin-left: 0;
 }
 input, textarea, .uneditable-input {
    width: 206px;
 }
 input, button, select, textarea {
     font-family: "Open Sans",Arial,sans-serif;
 }
 label, input, button, select, textarea {
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: 400;
     line-height: 20px;
 }
 button, input {
     line-height: normal;
 }
 button, input, select, textarea {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
 }
 user agent stylesheetinput[type="search"] {
    padding: 1px;
 }
 user agent stylesheetinput[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: searchfield;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 user agent stylesheetinput, input[type="password"], input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px inset;
    border-image-source: initial;
    border-image-slice: initial;
    border-image-width: initial;
    border-image-outset: initial;
    border-image-repeat: initial;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    cursor: auto;
}
user agent stylesheetinput, input[type="password"], input[type="search"] {
   -webkit-appearance: textfield;
   padding: 1px;
   background-color: white;
   border: 2px inset;
   border-image-source: initial;
   border-image-slice: initial;
   border-image-width: initial;
   border-image-outset: initial;
   border-image-repeat: initial;
   -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
   -webkit-user-select: text;
   cursor: auto;
}
user agent stylesheetinput, textarea, keygen, select, button {
   margin: 0em;
   font: -webkit-small-control;
   color: initial;
   letter-spacing: normal;
   word-spacing: normal;
   text-transform: none;
   text-indent: 0px;
   text-shadow: none;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: start;
}
user agent stylesheetinput, textarea, keygen, select, button, meter, progress {
   -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}
Pseudo ::before element
.k-animation-container, .k-widget, .k-widget *, .k-animation-container *, .k-widget    
:before, .k-animation-container :after, .k-block .k-header, .k-list-container {
   -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
   box-sizing: content-box;
}
Inherited from td#aria_active_cell.sg-grid-filter-cell
.k-grid td {
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 0 0 0 1px;
   padding: .4em .6em;
   overflow: hidden;
   line-height: 1.6em;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.sg-grid-filter-cell {
   background-color: #c2c2c2;
   white-space: nowrap;
   vertical-align: top!important;
}
Inherited from table
.k-grid table {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   border-collapse: separate;
   border-spacing: 0;
   empty-cells: show;
   border-width: 0;
   outline: 0;
}
table {
   max-width: 100%;
   background-color: transparent;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border-spacing: 0;
}
user agent stylesheettable {
   display: table;
   border-collapse: separate;
   border-spacing: 2px;
   border-color: gray;
}
Inherited from div.k-grid-header-wrap
.k-grid-header-wrap, .k-grid-footer-wrap {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
   zoom: 1;
}
Inherited from div.k-grid-header
div.k-grid-header, div.k-grid-footer {
   padding-right: 17px;
   border-bottom-style: solid;
   border-bottom-width: 1px;
   zoom: 1;
}
Inherited from div.k-grid.k-widget
.sg-grid, .k-grid {
   border: 0;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-weight: 400;
   line-height: 20px;
   color: #262626;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
.k-block, .k-widget, .k-popup, .k-content, .k-dropdown .k-input {
   color: #787878;
}
.k-grid, .k-listview {
   position: relative;
   zoom: 1;
}
.k-block, .k-widget {
line-height: normal;
   outline: 0;
}
Inherited from div.sg-grid.ng-scope.ng-isolate-scope
.sg-grid, .k-grid {
   border: 0;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-weight: 400;
   line-height: 20px;
   color: #262626;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: your going to have to add some code...

Comment: The browser doesn't add the ellipsis on it's own. Something in your code is doing it.

Comment: Are you using some JS plugin for filters ? Sometimes it might interfere with your own CSS

Comment: Inspect the element using Chrome to see what CSS is applied and where.

Comment: @Riskbreaker - added the stylesheet

Comment: @Aliassse - thanks for the reply, bot using any JS plugin for filters

Comment: @Popnoodles - thanks, just posted the css from Chrome's debugger

Comment: "Inherited from td#aria_active_cell.sg-grid-filter-cell
.k-grid td {
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 0 0 0 1px;
   padding: .4em .6em;
   overflow: hidden;
   line-height: 1.6em;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}"

Comment: @j08691 - thanks, I removed the text-overflow bit but that doesn't help in IE or FF.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why the question was downgraded?

Comment: Without seeing the code so that we can try to reproduce this, the best you'll get are guesses. And who knows why someone downvoted you. There's no accounting for taste.

Comment: @j08691 - lol! thanks. I knew that guesses were as much as I could expect without posting code but sometimes you get lucky!

Comment: @j08691 - I owe you a thousand thanks! It was the text-overflow: ellispsis on the grid's td. Funny thing is it didn't work for some reason when I removed it in the IE9's debugger but using jquery it did work. So thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The solution, pointed out by @j08691 was this class in the stylesheet:

```
Inherited from td#aria_active_cell.sg-grid-filter-cell .k-grid td { 
   border-style: solid; 
   border-width: 0 0 0 1px; 
   padding: .4em .6em; 
   overflow: hidden; 
   line-height: 1.6em; 
   vertical-align: middle; 
   text-overflow: ellipsis; // THIS WAS CAUSING THE ELLIPSIS!
}
```